# AWS CLI - aws ec2 describe-volumes to find the size of the root volume attached to an instance including the free space left in a table format

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to list all the default ebs root volumes sizes (c drive) with free space left including the instances names in our environment in table format. I have tried this command. Can someone help

```bash
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[*].{VolumeID:Attachments[0].VolumeId,InstanceID:Attachments[0]."Name=instance-id",size:Size,type:VolumeType.}' --output table
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current command?

Comment: For free space left you'll have pull metrics from cloudwatch.

Comment: Paolo it only gives the instance id, volume id and total size. i need to add total volume size left and instance name as well.

Comment: Tried this as well.                                                                                                        
 aws ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[*].{VolumeID:Attachments[0].VolumeId,InstanceID:Attachments[0]."Name=Instance-id",size:Size,type:VolumeType}' --output text

Answer (score 0):

AWS manages the *infrastructure*, such as provisioning Amazon EC2 instances and Amazon EBS volumes.

However, the *content* of the disk is **managed by your chosen Operating System** (eg Windows or Linux). AWS does not have access to the software or operating system running 'inside' your instance, so it has no knowledge of "free disk space".

Instead, you can [Collect metrics and logs from Amazon EC2 instances and on-premises servers with the CloudWatch agent - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html). The Agent is a bit of software installed on the EC2 instance that can query the Operating System to ask about free memory, disk space, etc. This data is then sent to **Amazon CloudWatch** where you can track the metric over time.